# What's the cause of leaking voltage in this cable?

Tags: voltage, cables

This is a 7x1 cable, made by some unknown company:

[image: cable]

When I connect 220V to two of these wires, other wires also get **~60V.** At first I thought I have some short circuit, there so I used a multimeter and checked all wires two by two and there was no short circuit.

How and why does voltage "leak" from two wires to other wires in this cable?

Comment: How long is the cable, and how are you measuring the 60V? It could be capacitance.

Comment: @JackB cable is 2 meter long, voltage measured with multimeter on AC voltage.

Comment: What's at the other end of the cable?

Comment: @HarrySvensson Nothing! lose wires in the air... just like the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wires have a significant capacitance to each other. If your only load on the end is the high impedance of your DMM (at least 1M, often 10M), then it's quite expected to be able to read such a voltage on unconnected wires. When you put a heavier load on them, the voltage will drop to near zero.

Comment: what's a "heavy load"? the max current wires gonna carry is about 3 to 5 ampere. also an off-topic question; that "capacitance" causes negative voltage (noise) on my DC logic level mosfet which uses 2 of those wires in the cable which should carry only 12V DC, what's the solution for that?

Comment: as you progressively reduce the resistance loading the end to below the 1M ohm of your meter, the voltage will progressively drop. Try a 1k resistor. Alternatively put a capacitor across the wires, which will attenuate the AC signal, without compromising the ability to put DC across them. The off topic question will need a schematic with it, so it's clear what you mean. Ask a new question for it.

Answer (score 3):

If you take two parallel conductors with an insulator between, you get a capacitor.  Ordinary cable may have a capacitance of only a few picofarads per metre.  This is very small, but with an AC voltage and a digital multimeter with a very high input resistance, it is enough to show a stray voltage on any un-connected cores of the cable.

If you were to try connecting a load across the two unconnected cores, the voltage would collapse to almost zero.

Comment: is there anyway to avoid that "stray voltage"? that is causing noise to my circuit!

Comment: @newbie connect all un-used cores to a ground.