# How to avoid noise/stray voltage in a cable which going to carry both AC and DC current?

Tags: voltage, noise, cables

The cable and it's capacitance discussed and answered in [This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/453738/whats-the-cause-of-leaking-voltage-in-this-cable/).

The schematic of my circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZQvbL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The load for the mosfet going to be a series of high wattage LEDs and for the AC voltage relays some AC motors etc...

The problem as discussed [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/453738/whats-the-cause-of-leaking-voltage-in-this-cable/) is the stray voltage ~60V on other wires when no load is connected, that stray voltage is causing noise and negative voltage on my DC mosfet. when mosfet is OFF there's a negative voltage `-1.7V~` at the output of it.

How can i eliminate this "capacitance noise" from my circuit and of course other wires in the cable?

*grounding unconnected wires is not practical in my case.*

Comment: How does the noise and negative voltage impact on functionality or performance?

Comment: @Andyaka first it's enough to lit an LED, second using power when there's no need for it and third it may damage or reduce the life of equipment in long run *probably*...

Comment: @Andyaka did you mean i can ignore this noise? as you can tell i'm a hobbyist and don't know much about this stuff... *btw your reputation is impressive!*

Comment: I'd be more concerned about your DC supply (and what else it connects to including you) inadvertently becoming connected to live and electrocuting someone.

Comment: @Andyaka so i shouldn't use a cable to carry both AC and DC current and should wire DC separately outside of the cable?

Comment: I assume this is a multi conductor cable? If you have not purchased the cable yet, you can get cable with shields.

Comment: Model the wire-to-wire coupling in your cable. Assume appropriate noise/spike slewrates, and compute the displacement currents from wire-to-wire. Given a current, how much upset should you expect (this is simply Ohms Law I * R).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i eliminate this "capacitance noise" from my circuit and of course other wires in the cable?

1. Don't use the same cable. Aside from this leakage, there are also safety and legislation aspects involved.
2. Buy special cable where the signal lines are shielded.
3. Load the line. Load it enough that for the capacitance of the maximum specified length it is unable to generate a high enough voltage to cause a problem.

Be aware that when you start running current trough the cable you are not only looking at capacitive coupling but also inductive coupling.

Comment: "Load the line", is there a way to calculate the required load?

Comment: @newbie Yes, a typical resistor divider, but then with impedance at 50 Hz.